# Java nio Path versus the regular java File API

Tags: java, path, hadoop

**This question is about the java.nio package, in particular, the Path class.**

I've always used the standard java File API, along with FileUtils for file based operations, reading, writing, checking availability, etc... and I've never had much of a problem...

...However, I've been seeing alot of use of the Path class in the java.nio package lately.  It seems as though there isn't a clear link in the Path API to the older, File API.

I thus have 3 questions which , hopefully, will help me reorient myself with the spirit of the Path API.

**1) Are we moving towards deprecation, or less usage, of the java.io File class ?**

**2) What are the benefits/reasons for adopting the java.nio Path class for file operations ?**

and

3) (less significant, but would be really helpful to know...) What is the relation (either in spirit, or at the code level) between java.nio Path and the org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **File** will stay, but already before Path sometimes URL.getStream was more versatile (file://... and http://). Now **Path** can have several file systems, like into a zip; maybe you encountered the old URL "..../xxx.jar!org/yyy/res/zzz.png".

2) Immediately: the event handling, watching changes on a directory and such.

Comment: So ...... are we going to see overlapping between the functionality of java.nio.Path/java.io.File

Comment: URI didn't replace URL. And also with File and Path there are too many interconnections and usages of File. At least three years probably before full deprecation.